# Can not delete a docker image because repository is missing

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I am not able to delete a docker image `library/memcached` with tag 1.4.22.

There are only three versions available for library/memcached on dockerhub:1.4.24, 1.4 and 1.

When I try to delete it, it throws an error `repository not found`.
Since its not a locally created image removing everything from /var/lib/docker also did not help.

I need to clean up docker from my server including all the mapped devices.
Please help.

Comment: did you try with `-f ` option : `docker rmi -f <IMAGE>`? And go through this https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/145

Comment: Yes.. it says "No such repository: memcached"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to remove this image.
So as I mentioned there was no source repository in dockerhub for memcached version I had, it was not allowing me to delete it.
I deleted complete docker folder from /var/lib and restarted docker.
It created docker folder again with all the relevant folders.